# python handling corruption line

Tags: python, exception, corruption

Do handling Corrupt lines by prepending "corrupt" as the result
#Other lines should be handled correctly

#3::::5 => corrupt:3::::5

## 3 5:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Hello World => corrupt:3 5:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 Hello World

```py
def f10(inFile, outFile):
    try:
        with open(outFile, "w") as op_file:
            for line in open(inFile):
                val = sum_of_factors(
                    *[[int(x) for x in y.split(" ")] for y in line.rstrip().split(":")]
                )
                print(val)
        op_file.write(str(val) + ":" + line.strip() + "\n")
        op_file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Error: Input file not found.")
    except IOError as e:
        print(f"Error: An IO error occurred - {e}")

f10("./input", "./output")
```

Comment: Please format your code/question appropriately because it's not readable currently.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.